# Change URL content dynamically

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am using PHP codeigniter framework. I want rewrite URL dynamically like below . For eg. I have function `get_catagory_wise_record` which list out all records of selected category. URL is  `controller/get_catagory_wise_record` I want to convert it like `controller/(selected category name here)`. I know I can use routes but how I can pass category name dynamically each time for routing so it will replace method name by selected category name.

Comment: you will not get good answer on SO, until your question is not well formatted and not with your tried code

Answer (score 0):

In the `routes.php` file add the below code(change it according to your database and parameters),

```
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB.php' );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->select('id,name')->get( 'categories' );// let categories table is here
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row ){
    // let you have category controller
    $route['category/'.$row->name]  ="category/get_catagory_wise_record/?id=".$row->id;
}
```